# XSLT for grouping and restructuring XML based on parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML file having structure like this-

```
<products>
 <product>
  <id>1</id>
  <type>fruits</type>
  <varieties>
   <variety>
    <id>a</id>
    <cost>100</cost>
    <availability>Y</availability>
   </variety>
   <variety>
    <id>b</id>
    <cost>75</cost>
    <availability>N</availability>
   </variety>
  </varieties>
 </product>
 <product>
  <id>2</id>
  <type>vegetables</type>
  <varieties>
   <variety>
    <id>c</id>
    <cost>50</cost>
    <availability>Y</availability>
   </variety>
   <variety>
    <id>d</id>
    <cost>55</cost>
    <availability>Y</availability>
   </variety>
  </varieties>
 </product>
</products>
```

I want to restructure the given XML based on products/product/id. The expected output would be as follows-

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
  <tr> 
   <td>1</td>
   <td>fruits</td>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>Y</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>1</td>
   <td>fruits</td>
   <td>b</td>
   <td>75</td>
   <td>N</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
   <td>2</td>
   <td>vegetables</td>
   <td>c</td>
   <td>50</td>
   <td>Y</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>2</td>
   <td>vegetables</td>
   <td>d</td>
   <td>55</td>
   <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this XSLT but it is not returning the expected xml.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <products>
  <product>
   <varieties>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product/varieties/variety" /> 
   </varieties>
  </product>
 </products>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="products" >
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
   <xsl:for-each select="products/product">
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="type" /></td>
     <xsl:for-each select="varieties/variety" >
      <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="cost" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="availability" /></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tr> 
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are applying templates to 'variety` - but you don't have a template matching `variety`. You have a template matching `root` - but there is no element named `root`. And the contents of the template matching `/` (which is the only template that gets executed) does not match your intended output.

Comment: Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `variety` does not match `Variety`.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k i have modified my XSLT. could you please suggest the changes?

Comment: No. This is really a trivial task. Create a row for each `variety`, and use `<xsl:value-of select="../../id" />` and `<xsl:value-of select="../../type"/>` to get the ancestor product's id and type respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against /products, so the below should give you what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/products" >
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
   <xsl:for-each select="product">
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="type" /></td>
     <xsl:for-each select="varieties/variety" >
      <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="cost" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="availability" /></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tr> 
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IMHO your html output could be quite messy if you have varying numbers of varieties for each product. I don't know your application but you may want to consider using rowspan on the first 2 columns based on count of varieties and have one row per variety.

**Updated based on OP feedback**

I've included the code to span the repeated data, if you don't like that then feel free to remove the if start and end tags and remove the rowspan attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/products" >
<html>
 <body>
     <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
        <xsl:variable name="ProductID" select="id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ProductType" select="type"/>
        <xsl:variable name="VarietyCount" select="count(varieties/variety)"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="varieties/variety" >
            <tr>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                     <td rowspan="{$VarietyCount}"><xsl:value-of select="$ProductID" /></td>
                     <td rowspan="{$VarietyCount}"><xsl:value-of select="$ProductType" /></td>
                </xsl:if>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="cost" /></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="availability" /></td>
            </tr> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @RT72, your given XSLT return all the elements under '<varieties>' into a list. my requirement is to list all the elements in every node '<variety>' with their parent node elements '<product>'.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean, I get the exact results you've put in your original post - do you want something different as output - if so can you update your question to clarify?

Comment: Hi @RT72, I need to apply something like grouping concept here. Let me explain the concept. I have 2 products <fruits> and <vegetables>. Under each product I have 2 varieties which is being referred with <id><cost><availability>. Now, I want to group elements in XML based on variety and each group should be having elements as follows-
<id>(id of fruits/vegetables), <type>(fruits/vegetables), <id>(id of variety), <cost>, <availability>.

Comment: So I understand, you're saying you want XML output NOT html output as your original post suggested?

Comment: I am OK for XML or HTML format for getting the data with desired conditions. But preferably HTML.

Comment: Ok so - what html output do you get with the code I supplied?

Comment: I am unable to paste the output in the form of code in the comment. 
You may please refer http://xsltransform.net/ and then copy paste my XML and your XSLT.

The output i got was 2 rows - one for <type> - fruits and another one was for <type> - vegetables having all the elements for 2 varieties.

Comment: If you see the response, you have 2 rows and each row returning all the varieties into a single row where first 2 <td> refers <id> & <type> from products/product,  next 3 <td> refers first <variety> and the last 3 <td> refers second <variety>.
I need 4 rows - 2 rows for <type> = fruits and 2 rows for <type> = vegetables. Each row should have 5 elements - <id> & <type> from products/product, <id> & <cost> & <availability> from varieties/variety.